# ember-data hasMany and belongsTo (habtm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to learn new thing in ember every day and I'm stuck with ember-data and hasMany associations.

**used libs**

```
Rails 3.2.13
gem act_as_taggable_on
ember RC2
ember-data (rev: 12), RESTfulAdapter
```

**issue**

I want to add a tagging feature which means "add and remove tags to posts". So I need a post model which hasMany tags. But the same tag can be used on different posts so a tag hasMany posts as well.

Post.js

```
App.Post = Ember.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
  body: DS.attr('string')
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
})
```

Tag.js

```
App.Tag = Ember.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
  posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post')
})
```

After trying to add a new tag to a post and commit it's changes, my json payload misses always the post_id.

JSON sent to rails

```
{"tag"=>{"name"=>"test tag name"}}
```

Using a join model didn't help and it feels like both are bad approach at all.

I've read through the test specs of ember-data but there was no habtm or similar test case, so maybe it's just not supported.

**Question**

What is the ember way to define hasMany and belongsTo associations on both sides or is there a better way in general to solve my problem?

If ember-data is not supporting it, how could my issue be solved?

Comment: Can this be solved by overriding the RESTAdapter for a tag model?

Answer (score 0):

By default the rest adapter only sends foreign keys on the belongsTo side. You would need to overwrite this hook https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L169 to add the hasMany ids in the non-embedded case as well.

Comment: Thanks IgorT. Maybe I'm missing something, but how does you model look like in your case? Currently I've a hasMany on **both** sides. Is there somewhere a documentation for overriding parts of the serializer?

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. Can you post a jsbin? There is a nice default ember-data jsbin here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuxijava/1/edit